# Listview inside a ViewCell in separate file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have List View in Main-Page. I am using template selector to choose the templates which are resides in separate files(ViewCell). Now I need to use a list view in the selected template(separate file), but it gives run-time error and I am not able to get what is the error also. Below is the code snippet.

**MainPage**

```
 <ListView   Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True"  
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RequestTemplateSelector }" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding LstInventoryRequests}" >
                    </ListView>
```

**LstInventoryRequests(List of below class object)**

```
Class 
{
    public string IssuedOn { get; set; }
    public string IssueId { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<InventoryDetailItemData>  ItemDetails { get; set; }
}
```

**InventoryDetailItemData**

```
 public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int RequestedQty { get; set; }
    public int IssuedQty { get; set; }
```

**Inside ViewCell(Separate file) being selected by templateselector**

```
 <ListView 
         SeparatorVisibility="None" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemDetails}">
                 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <ViewCell >
                             <ViewCell.View>
                                   <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                              </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                         </DataTemplate>
                      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
```

It gives me Run-time error and not able to find what is the issue in the above code.
Can someone please help me finding it out?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I got the below information from output window              11-24 18:52:57.868 W/dalvikvm(19807): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41db3c08)
An unhandled exception occured.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use ListView Grouping .

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove these.  `<ViewCell.View>  </ViewCell.View>` from your code.

Let me know if it works.